# Javascript: add 1 day to date

Tags: javascript

Using the following code to add an extra day to a Date, however, it returns the value in numbers.

```
expiryDate = oldDate.setDate(olDate.getDate() + 1);
document.write(expiryDate);
```

Returns `1396393199000`

Then, i tried formatting

```
expiryDate = oldDate.setDate(olDate.getDate() + 1);
document.write(format(expiryDate, "%2D/%2M/%2Y"));
```

And I get the following error;

> Error while evaluating document Date '1396393199000': invalid
>   character at position 5 ('3') JavaScript: error while evaluating
>   script 'content htmlContent'.

Any advice?

Comment: What's the `format()` function?

Comment: Also, you have `olDate` and `oldDate`, is that a typo?

Comment: Try passing `oldDate` to `format()` instead of `expiryDate`. The `setDate()` method will mutate the original object.

Comment: `setDate` doesn't return a new Date

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ahh, it looks like I read it wrong.

Comment: @kevin Schmid your solution worked, just needed to convert it to a date object!

Comment: You already have a Date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expiryDate isnt valid, when you create dates you need to create a new Date();

Like:

```
var oldDate = new Date();
var expiryDate = new Date(oldDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() + 1));
```

then you can run...

```
var oldDate = new Date();
var expiryDate = new Date(oldDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() + 1));
document.write(expiryDate.getDate() + '/' + (expiryDate.getMonth() +1) + '/' + expiryDate. getFullYear());
```

Or you can use your format function from whatever library you are using...